# Make item in hand invisible

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I saw a server that made the item in your hand invisible, but they showed in the inventory, is it possible to make the item that you're holding invisible to other players? I need it for a map I'm creating.

Comment: so you want to be able to see the item in inventory but not hand

Comment: Yes, I'm making a Among Us map, and I wanted to make like: /testfor @e[name=Kill] and when the player throws the item I use /kill @p[tag=Crewmate, r = 3].

Comment: would you be open to alternative methods that achieve the same end result but a bit differently?

Comment: Every suggestion is accepted.